# Retrieve data from two tables with missing links

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where to retrieve data with specific criteria and the only relationship between two tables is ID. See the tables below.
The target join for this case should be co_id, however the table2 doesn't have this column. I need to retrieve anyone in co_ID with LDR=1 and email='' and Desig ='0'. in the exam below the result should be '0000383' in DD 0000 no one have desg 1 and LDR is one but email is null.

Simple syntax missing the join part.

```
select Desig, LDR,Table2.*  
from  Table1, Table2 
where (LDR =1 and email ='') and (Desig = 0)

Table1 
id      Desig LDR    
0000121  0     0        
0000383  0     1                
0000509  0     1       
0000593  1     0      
0000626  1     0
0000526  0     1
0000523  0     0

------------------------------
Table2
id     | co_id   |  FULL_NAME    |     EMAIL
0000121  DD 0000    Mary Jen    
0000383  DD 0000    Mat Howard       
0000509  YY 0000    Dorothy Bolan    example1@example.com
0000593  YY 0000    Pat Schu    
0000626  XX 0000    Lisa m    
0000526  XX 0000    Lori de
0000523  XX 0000    Donna tr
```

To sum it what i need is to retrieve id with ldr = 1 and email = ' ' if desig = 0 for each co_id. hope this make more sense.

Comment: OP have you tried the below answers?

Comment: what i need is to retrieve id with ldr = 1 and email = ' ' if desig = 0 for each co_id. hope this make more sense.

Comment: @Messi Could you show your expect result? that really help

Answer (score 1):

You can join from one column of one table to multiple columns in a second table like this:

```
select * from table1 a join table2 b on a.id=b.id or a.id=b.co_id  
where  LDR =1 and email =''  and  Desig = 0
```

Comment: what i need is to retrieve id with ldr = 1 and email = ' ' if desig = 0 for each co_id. hope this make more sense.

Comment: what i need is to retrieve id with ldr = 1 and email = ' ' if desig = 0 for each co_id. hope this make more sense.

Comment: no this won't work. co_id have many id and only id can have the ldr and desig with 1

Answer (score 1):

It gives me correct result for your data.

```
create table #table(id varchar(10),Design int,LDR int)

create table #table1(id varchar(10),co_id varchar(10),fname varchar(10),email varchar(20))

insert into #table values('0000121',0,0),('0000383',0,1),('0000509',0,1),('0000593',1,0)

insert into #table1 values('0000121','DD 0000','Mary Jen' ,''),('0000383','DD 0000','Mat Howard' ,''),('0000509','YY 0000','Dorlan' ,'example1@exle.com'),('0000593','YY 0000','Pat Schu' ,'')

select  t1.Design,t1.LDR,t2.* from #table t1 join #table1 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.LDR = 1 and t2.email ='' and t1.Design = 0
```

Comment: what i need is to retrieve id with ldr = 1 and email = ' ' if desig = 0 for each co_id. hope this make more sense.

Comment: The example is not showing the full concept of the wanted result. if DD 0000 have one more row with Desig 1 it will show  0000383 because you joined with ID.

Comment: I updated my post. i added rows in the example tables.

Comment: what is criteria for co_id column.

Comment: co_id is as a group id of records.

Comment: co_id is as a group id of records. select records if records in co_id doesn't have desig 1 and (ldr 1 and  email ' '). if table 2 have column co_id i could join by this column and solved the problem but this is the challenge i have.

Comment: totally two columns are achieved, all of your criteria. So, what can do...?